# how to create Expandable layout in android?

Tags: android, view, expandable

Can any one help me to create an expandable view like more button in android market?
when we click on more button it will expand the view with more details about the application in android market place..

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

thanks

sathish

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on something similar.

At the moment it looks like this in the **more/less** bar mode:[image: more/less view layout]

It is still a work in progress but the project and source can be viewed [here](http://www.djpsoft.com/projects/moredroid)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to implement this is to use [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). When you click on More button fetch more data and use [addAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) method to add all newly fetched data to the adapter. [addAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29) automatically will propagate changes to the ListView so don't bother to notify it explicit.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but i would like to create a view which is having not only text , some buttons and links and some other edittext fields. So how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ModifiedExpandableList extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_copy);
        // set our list
        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Need no icon as of now
        mExpandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
        registerForContextMenu(mExpandableListView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0,"dd");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

        int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
        if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
            int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
            Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * A simple adapter which maintains an ArrayList of photo resource Ids. 
     * Each photo is displayed as an image. This adapter supports clearing the
     * list of photos and adding a new photo.
     *
     */
    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        Context mContext;
        public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context){
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names", "Fish Names" };
        private String[][] children = {
                { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
                { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
                { "Fluffy", "Snuggles","ddef","afadsfasf" },
                { "Goldy", "Bubbles","sfef","dafs" }
        };

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            int result=4;

            return result;
       }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = null;
            // changed here
                LayoutInflater li = ModifiedExpandableList.this.getLayoutInflater();
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.child_view,null);
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                tv.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
                ImageView im = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
                im.setBackgroundDrawable(ModifiedExpandableList.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.closearrow));
            return v;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // change here to modify parent group layout
            View v = null;
            LayoutInflater li = ModifiedExpandableList.this.getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.parent_view,null);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            tv.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
            ImageView im = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
            im.setBackgroundDrawable(ModifiedExpandableList.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.closearrow));
            if(isExpanded){
                im.setBackgroundDrawable(ModifiedExpandableList.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.closearrow_b));
            }
            return v;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```